# Material is black at edges when rendered

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials

[image: All's fine in the Material Preview][image: In rendered view and in the image renders, some parts of the texture appear black.]Some areas of the PBR textures+Principled shader material that I used appear black when rendered. This only happens from some angles. I tried recalculating normals, merging by distance but to no avail. Any help appreciated. It looks fine in the material preview, just get this black on the sides based on the viewing angle only in the rendered view.

Comment: You're gonna have to zoom in on the problematic areas and/or mark them, this screenshot tells me nothing.

Comment: apologies, I have highlighted the problematic area in red in the picture.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved by adding a Normal Map in the PBR node setup. Missed that earlier...